# Display size of files categorized per extension

Tags: windows, file-management

I am looking for a Windows(7) utility which displays the space taken up (under a folder) categorized by the file extension, like .obj = 83.5 MB (255 files), .sdf = 87.8 MB (1 file).

Does anyone know of a program that does this? (either on the command-line or in a window)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) and experiment with the ability to zoom.

Comment: +1 looks good -- will download and play with it this week-end, will let you know, thanks!

Comment: It look a while to get it compiled under VS2010, but it is an extremely nice program!  I miss some useful features like selecting multiple folders, zoom using the file-types pane -- I might even try modifying the program when I have a bit of time :) -- thanks a lot!!